# React-Native Align Issue

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I just want the Icon to be on the left and the text to be on center.

I have this structure:

```
<View style={styles.mainContainer}>
    <Error screen={screen}/>
    <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
      {back &&
             <Icon
              raised
              name='arrow-back'
              onPress={ onBackPress }
              containerStyle={styles.back}/>
      }
      <Text style={styles.header}>{ title }</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
      { children }
    </View>
  </View>
```

Kinda like this:

-> MainContainer

--> HeaderContainer

----> Back button

----> Title

```
mainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start'
  },
  headerContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    // ommited for clarity
  },
  back: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-start'
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 24,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
```

But it doesnt work as it produces:
[image]

I also tried adding in HeaderContainer:

```
justifyContent: 'space-between',
```

and a blank `<View />`, but the result is not good:

[image]

As you can see, it's not centered really.

**Edit** Produces:

[image]

It's not really centered, because we put an imaginary thrid element. Can we do it with only two elemets? One in start and other on center?

Why is it not posible?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
     {leftContent}
  </View>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}>
    {centerContent}
  </View>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
    {rightContent}
  </View>
</View>
```

Don't forget to set `textAlign: 'center'` if center component is `<Text>` or `textAlign: 'right'` if the right component is `Text`.

Comment: @MarcoNoronha did you add `textAlign: center` to `header`?

Comment: Yes @binchik . I didnt forget your note.

Comment: @MarcoNoronha Try to add `flex: 1` to header.

Answer (score 0):

Put your Icon and text in separate Views and asign a flex to it something like this

```
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <Error screen={screen}/>
        <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
            <View style={{flex:.3,alignSelf:'flex-start}}>     
               {back &&
                   <Icon
                    raised
                    name='arrow-back'
                    onPress={ onBackPress }
                   containerStyle={styles.back}/>
                }
           </View>
           <View style={{flex:.7,alignSelf:'flex-end',alignItems:'center'}}>    
                <Text style={styles.header}>{ title }</Text>
           </View>    
    </View>
    <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
       { children }
    </View>
  </View>
```

I think it shoud fix the problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Almost though. The text isnt centered with the 100% of the width. It's kinda what I did with the 'space-between' workaround. :( Also, this breaks when there's no button.